# Sencha Touch - Nested List - Refreshing a list item. (Using getItemTextTpl to se Template )

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, nested-lists, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a nested list with a template by using getItemTextTpl. Template is simple it checks for a flag and if true it shows a button on a list item. If false show no button.

When on the list item I press the button (It's a delete button) I want to refresh that list item to not show the button. To make the button change I have to navigate up two levels and back down for it to update the list item.

My problem is getting the list item to refresh/Update. Can force the template to check the list item again etc? I can get the button to fire the event.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for the display layer:

why not just use css to apply/change the class of the delete button to hide it? then you don't have to refesh anything.

then you can programically set the value in your code, or send to the server to make sure the status is set when the view reloads at another point.